# Entity-framework doesn't save changes to database

Tags: entity-framework, save, savechanges

I have a problem with saving changes to the database with entity framework. I'm using three tables; AspNetUsers, tblCountry, and tblCountry_AspNetUsers.

tblCountry_AspNetUsers consists of two columns; UserId and CountryId, which creates a one-to-many relationship between tblCountry and AspNetUsers.

Currently, what I want to do is change the country of a specific user, but entity framework doesn't let me access the tblCountry_AspNetUsers database, and instead creates an ICollection of AspNetUsers on tblCountry. I could assign the Id on the AspNetUser directly, but I don't want to start adding/removing columns from identity tables just yet since I'm using database first, and I've heard it can lead to problems.

Anyway, I can remove just fine from the ICollection and save those changes to the database, but when I try to add the same user to a different country, it doesn't save to the database properly, but I can find the user in the context object when debugging.

I've tried attaching and changing the entitystate to both added and modified, but when I try to do this, it breaks out of the method and doesn't update the database. (basically it freezes when I try to attach)

**My code for editing a user looks like the following:**

(Note that UserManager handles the identity usermodel, ApplicationUser,, which is not the same as AspNetUsers in this aspect)

(Also, tblCountry.AspNetUsers refers to the ICollection of users assigned to a specific country)

```
 ...
            var aspuser = new AspNetUsers();
            using (DbContext dc = new DbContext())
            {
                aspuser = dc.AspNetUsers.First(x => x.Id == userid);

                var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userid);

                user.Email = updatedUser.UserName;
                user.UserName = updatedUser.Email;

                var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                aspuser.tblCountry.AspNetUsers.Remove(aspuser);

                await dc.SaveChangesAsync();  

            }

            using (DbContext dc = new DbContext())
            {
                var c = _country.GetById(newcountryid);
                c.AspNetUsers.Add(aspuser);

                await dc.SaveChangesAsync();  
            }

            return Users(userid);
        }
```

It would be extremely easy if it was a table I could access directly, but with an ICollection like this I'm confused as to what I should do to make it work, and I appreciate any input!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This line `aspuser = dc.AspNetUsers.First(x => x.Id == userid);` is inside `using (DbContext dc = new DbContext())` which means that object aspuser  is detached from context when you leave that block. You should do:

```
var c = _country.GetById(newcountryid);
            c.AspNetUsers.Add(aspuser);

            await dc.SaveChangesAsync();
```

in the same using block as the above code, why did you separate it?

Comment: I just tried separating them to see what difference it maked, but even when they're in the same block as the remove function, it doesn't save the new AspNetUsers collection to the database for some reason.

Comment: Wait a sec, if you have tblCountry_AspNetUsers table then it is many to many relationship, not one to many, and Entity should create ICollection of Countries on AspNetUser class also. Do you have that property?

Comment: No, since I use the UserId as primary key in tblCountry_AspNetUsers.

What I have in the AspNetUser class though is;  

public virtual tblCountry tblCountry { get; set; }

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with me trying to add something manually to the AspNetUsers table without using Identity's own class (ApplicationUser)?